# Linq to SQL: How to update data using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net

I am using linq to sql. I want to update my changed in object question using linq to sql using stored procedure any body have idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your procedure. Drag it to the data context designer. It'll generate a method for you. Just call it with the appropriate arguments and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It can literally be as easy as drag/dropping the store procedure in the DBML editor in Visual Studio.

[See here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2008/02/19/linq-to-sql-and-stored-procedures-visual-studio-2008-and-repository-factory.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the stored procedure in the DBML editor in Visual Studio.

When you go to call your stored procedure you can just call it directly. You don't need to add any special LINQ query to do this:

```
using (MyDataContext db = MyContextFactory.CreateContext())
{
    db.spStoredProcedure(parameters);
}
```

Comment: This is not still the right answer. I want some thing like InsertOnSubmit like for update.

Comment: InsertOnSubmit is used for Table data, when you call stored procedures you don't use the InsertOnSubmit. Can you maybe explain what you are attempting a bit more (code example?) and that might clear up the solution.